# Qemu - How to specify HDD file

Tags: virtualbox, qemu

I'm trying to install ESXI on `qemu` a VM. During the installation I don't see `esxi.qcow2` file size being increased. I'm not sure if its writing to the disk file or not.

`esxi.qcow2` file size is still 193 KB and not increasing at all.

This is the command I used:

qemu-system-x86_64 -boot d -cdrom VMware-esxi6.iso -m 4096 -cpu Westmere -machine q35 -smp cpus=2,cores=2  -hda esxi.qcow2 -name "Esxi_6.0"

Answer (score 0):

##### Create your esxi.qcow2 as below:

```
qemu-img create -f qcow2 esxi.qcow2 40G
```

##### Then try again:

```
qemu-system-x86_64 -enable-kvm -m 4096 -cdrom VMware-esxi6.iso -hda esxi.qcow2
```

Now it should boot fine with the fixed size you choosed for your esxi.qcow2 drive.